# if no host name present error

Tags: vbscript, hta

If a user enters the an incorrect hostname.  i want the script to display a msgbox "PC wmi broken or is offline"   it diplays an error but as this is being sent out to others, i'd just like a basic error msg box

```
Sub WindowsLoad1
    strHTML = strHTML & "<br>" & "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='white''>"
    strComputer = MachineName.Value
    strHTML = strHTML & "<b>Sys Info</b><br>&nbsp;<br>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "</font><font face='Arial' size='2'>"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each objComputer in colComputer
        strHTML = strHTML & "<b>Hostname</b>: " & objComputer.Name & "<br>"
        strHTML = strHTML & "<b>Current User</b>: " & objComputer.UserName & "<br>"
        strHTML = strHTML & "<b>Manufacturer</b>: " & objComputer.Manufacturer & "<br>"
        strHTML = strHTML & "<b>Model</b>: " & objComputer.Model & "<br>"
    Next

    strHTML = strHTML& "<br>" & "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='white''>"
    strComputer = MachineName.Value
    strHTML = strHTML& "<b>Serial Number</b><br>&nbsp;<br>"
    strHTML = strHTML&"</font><font face='Arial' size='2'>"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        strHTML4 = strHTML4 & " " & objItem.SerialNumber & "<br><br>"                
    next

    strHTML3 = "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='white''>"
    strComputer = MachineName.Value
    strHTML3 = strHTML3 & "<b>Windows Operating System Summary</b><br>&nbsp;<br>"
    strHTML3 = strHTML3 &"</font><font face='Arial' size='2'>"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        strHTML3 = strHTML3 & "<b>Caption</b>: " & objItem.Caption & "<br>"
        strHTML3 = strHTML3 & "<b>Version</b>: " & objItem.Version & "<br>"
        strHTML3 = strHTML3 & "<b>Service Pack</b>: " & objItem.ServicePackMajorVersion  & "<br>"
    Next

    strHTML3 = strHTML3 & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='white''>"
    'strHTML3 = strHTML3 & "<b>Last Reboot</b><br>&nbsp;<br>"
    strHTML3 = strHTML3 & "</font><font face='Arial' size='2'>"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        dtmInstallDate = objItem.LastBootUpTime
        'WMIDateStringToDate = FormatDateTime(dtmInstallDate,1) & " " & FormatDateTime(dtmInstallDate,4)
        'WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Left(dtmInstallDate, 4) & "/" & Mid(dtmInstallDate, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(dtmInstallDate, 7, 2) _
        '& " " & Mid (dtmInstallDate, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmInstallDate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmInstallDate, 13, 2))
        WMIDateStringToDate= dtmInstallDate
        'strHTML3 = strHTML3 & "<b>Computer Last Booted </b>: " & WMIDateStringToDate & "<br>"
    Next

    strHTML2 = "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='white''>"
    strComputer = MachineName.Value
    strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>Network Adapter Properties</b><br>&nbsp;<br>"
    strHTML2 = strHTML2 &"</font><font face='Arial' size='2'>"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>Description</b>: " & objItem.Description & "<br>"
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>Physical (MAC) address</b>: " & objItem.MACAddress & "<br>"
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>Host name</b>: " & objItem.DNSHostName & "<br>"

        If Not IsNull(objItem.IPAddress) Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(objItem.IPAddress)
                strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>IP address</b>: " & objItem.IPAddress(i) & "<br>"
            Next
        End If

        If Not IsNull(objItem.IPSubnet) Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(objItem.IPSubnet)
               strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>Subnet</b>: " & objItem.IPSubnet(i) & "<br>"
            Next
        End If

        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>DHCP server</b>: " & objItem.DHCPServer & "<br>"
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>Primary WINS server</b>: " & objItem.WINSPrimaryServer & "<br>"
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<b>Secondary WINS server</b>: " &  objItem.WINSSecondaryServer & "<br>&nbsp;<br>"
    Next
    DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML & strHTML4 & strhtml3 & strhtml2 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code snippet with proper [error handling](http://ss64.com/vb/onerror.html) could help:

```
Sub WindowsLoad1
    strHTML = strHTML & "<br>" & "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='white''>"
    strComputer = MachineName.Value
    strHTML = strHTML & "<b>Sys Info</b><br>&nbsp;<br>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "</font><font face='Arial' size='2'>"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
             & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
      On Error Goto 0
    Else
      msgbox "Data for current computer displayed due to the error: " _
          & Err.Description _
        , vbOKOnly + vbExclamation _
        , "An error occured"
      On Error Goto 0
      strComputer = "."
      MachineName.Value = strComputer
      Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                   & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    End If
    Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
    '''''''''''''''''''
    ' etc.
    '''''''''''''''''''
```